# Using css to style the grid axis in vis.js

Tags: javascript, css, vis.js

I have been using vis.js (version 4.11.0) and have been attempting to style the grid axis using the information [here](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Styles). I can make the samples work to block out weekends but I'd like to block out public holidays as well. It looks as though I should be able to do this using something like:

```
 .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-march.vis-date25{
  background: red;
}
```

but this does not work. Does anyone have a sample using the vis-{month} or vis-{dateX} classes?

Comment: Have you tried 'background-color: red'

Comment: Also try to simplify your css selector to something like .vis-march.vis-date25

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Depending on the zoom level, the grids get certain css classes attached.

Can it be that you're not on the right zoom level? I.e. `.vis-date25` is not there when you've zoomed in to hour or minute level.